# .NET Compact Framework, WCF service, compression and DIGEST authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'm trying to put a number of features together, which is proving increasingly difficult due to the limitations of the .NET Compact Framework.

Specifically, I've got a WCF service and I'm writing a mobile device client for it. The catch? I want to use some sort of data compression (due to a very slow modem connected to said device) and HTTP DIGEST authentication (which is already in place on the site hosting the WCF service).

I've followed [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maagniho/archive/2008/12/24/gzip-message-encoding-for-wcf-applications-written-using-net-compact-framework.aspx) to get the compression and generated code needed for the WCF service client.

I am, however, struggling with the HTTP DIGEST. I've no idea how to add this functionality.

Previously I didn't use compression and as such I connected to the WCF service using SOAP, using a simple WebService reference, and to add HTTP DIGEST I had to override the `GetWebRequest` method and add the required headers manually. This time around the generated classes seem to give very little leeway and there isn't much I can override. Also, all security or authentication parameters seem to be designed for SSL, rather than such basic authentication schemes.

To summarize: how can I create a WCF client using compression and HTTP DIGEST authentication using .NET Compact Framework?

EDIT:
Here's the code I've currently got:

```
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding customBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding();
        CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement compressionBindingElement = new CompressionMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        customBinding.Elements.Add(compressionBindingElement);
        HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
        customBinding.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);
        EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:5100/Service.svc");
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(customBinding, endPoint);
```

I suspect I somehow need to add the HTTP DIGEST functionality to the `CustomBinding` class, but I don't know how.

I suspect I should also note, that while I am using .NET Compact Framework 3.5, I am creating a Windows CE application. As such, I didn't bother downloading Windows Mobile 6 SDKs. If these SDKs add more functionality which can be used in Window CE applications and are required for the HTTP DIGEST to work, please let me know.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer from a similar question can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28998391/892836

Comment: @ToniRossmann It was a long time ago when we did that project, and I've already posted the solution we went with. That said, your answer seems to forget about our need to have compression enabled. Our application was using digest and the infrastructure was working around that. I suppose your code could be rewritten to make use of Digest fairly easy (since we've already had to do it manually), but I'm unsure how that would all fit together, nor can I really check as our original application has evolved and no longer uses any Compact Framework elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up disabling the DIGEST authentication for devices running .NET CF. It's not as safe, but we figured the data send and retrieved by the devices running .NET CF in our case isn't THAT sensitive, so all we really need to do is validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the client is running on the .NET Compact Framework 3.5, you can use WCF to invoke the service and use the built-in support for HTTP Digest authentication without requiring SSL.

Here's how to programmatically configure a WCF client to use Digest authentication with the [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://server/myservice");
var client = new MyServiceClient(binding, endpoint);

// We have to set the actual credentials on the client proxy object
// before invoking the service:
client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = "me";
client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = "password";

try
{
    client.MyServiceOperation();
    client.Close();
}
catch
{
    client.Abort();
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [The WCF subset supported by the .NET Compact Framework 3.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/08/21/the-wcf-subset-supported-by-netcf.aspx)
- [WCF Guidance for Mobile Developers (see page 66 for HTTP Digest Authentication)](http://wcfguidanceformobile.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I am a little bit confused by your response. Specifically, the .config code you posted. I assume this is for the mobile application, but, to my (possibly limited) knowledge, Compact Framework applications doesn't support App.config. As such, I need to manually set all those binding **in code**. You also seem to have forgotten that I need to use the compression I mentioned earlier which means I need to use a `CustomBinding` class. I will edit my question to include some more details.

Comment: @Shaamaan Absolutely correct, the .NET Compact Framework does not support application configuration files. I updated my answer.

Comment: It's quite possible I'm missing some vital SDK from my system, or you are forgetting that this is .NET Compact Framework. For example as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement_members%28VS.90%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.authenticationscheme%28VS.90%29.aspx), the `AuthenticationScheme` property of `HttpTransportBindingElement` is not available in CFW, and indeed, Visual Studio didn't recognise the properties.

Comment: @Shaamaan Indeed I forgot to check whether the [HttpTransportBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.authenticationscheme.aspx) was supported on the Compact Framework. At this point my only conclusion is that it may just not be possible to achieve what you're asking for on the Compact Framework. You may have to look at an alternative way to implement compression that doesn't involve custom bindings.

Comment: Thank you. However, I would like to note that your suggestion to use `BasicHttpBinding` is also flawed. The `TransportCredentialOnly` mode and the `Digest` credential types are missing from CFW ([`HttpClientCredentialType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.httpclientcredentialtype%28VS.90%29.aspx), [`WebHttpSecurityMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348328%28VS.90%29.aspx)). As such, the PDF you linked seems to be completely wrong about DIGEST, unless it's implemented manually. If there is a way to implement DIGEST in an easy fashion, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to use HttpWebRequest (manually) and specify ClientCredentials, instead of the generated classes from NetCFSvcUtil which does not support authentication.
The only WS-Security specification it supports on CF with WCF is to effectively use message security with a Mutual Certificate exchange. (Which by the way has a memory leak which a colleage and I found: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727247/native-memory-leak-in-wcf-proxy-client-with-mutual-certificate-security-in-net-compact-framework-3-5-on-windows-ce-6-0)

Of note, the generated `CFClientBase` also has a memory leak which can be worked around, see: http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2013/03/31/memory-leak-in-cfclientbaselttgt-service-proxy-for-compact-framework-.net.aspx

For reference: The WCF subset supported by NetCF: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2007/08/21/the-wcf-subset-supported-by-netcf.aspx